# Parsing switch statements with Happy

Tags: haskell, happy

So, I'm trying to parse code containg switch statements like this

```
function (a : Boolean) equals (b : Boolean) : Boolean {
        switch (a) {
         case true:
                switch (b) {
                 case true:
                        return (true);
                 case false:
                        return (false);
                }
         case false:
                switch (b) {
                 case true:
                        return (false);
                 case false:
                        return (true);
                }
        }
};
```

with

```
switch
    : "switch" expression "{" cases "}" {
        Switch $2 $4
    }
    ;

cases
    : case cases {
        ($1 : $2)
    }
    | case {
        [$1]
    }
    ;

case
    : "case" pattern ":" caseStatements {
        Case $2 $4
    }
    ;

caseStatements
    : caseStatement ";" caseStatements {
        ($1 : $3)
    }
    | caseStatement {
        [$1]
    }
    ;

caseStatement
    : assignment {
        AssignmentCaseStatement $1
    }
    | return {
        ReturnCaseStatement $1
    }
    | switch {
        SwitchCaseStatement $1
    }
    ;
```

but I keep getting:

```
certa: user error (../examples/Certa/BooleanLogic.certa:16: Parse error at token 'case')
```

when I run the generated parser. The strange thing here is that it fails on the *second* instance of the "case" keyword, but not the *first*. Why in the world would that be?

Comment: It's easier to help if you post a runnable code snippet (but small as possible).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your non-recursive leg of caseStatements include a semi-colon?

i.e.

```
caseStatements
    : caseStatement ";" caseStatements {
        ($1 : $3)
    }
    | caseStatement ";" {
        [$1]
    }
    ;
```